# How can we generate Keyboard interrupts using python

Tags: python, linux, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt

Is there a way to generate Keyboard interrupt without actually pressing a key on keyboard using a python program in linux. The interrupt should look like if someone has pressed a key on the keyboard and the complete system should get that interrupt irrespective of the currently focused window. For example if I have opened an editor and my python program generates an interrupt for key "A", then "A" should get printed in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[python-uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/)

Here is the example:

```
import uinput

device = uinput.Device([
        uinput.KEY_E,
        uinput.KEY_H,
        uinput.KEY_L,
        uinput.KEY_O,
        ])

device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_H)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_E)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_L)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_L)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_O)
```